# Error in JSP: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jsp, glassfish, nullpointerexception

I run my website (in jsp) and it throws this error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And here is the head of the JSP file:

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<%
    String usrnameSession = null;
    usrnameSession = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
    if(usrnameSession == null){
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
    }
%><head>blah...</head>
```

When i remove this block:

```
<%
        String usrnameSession = null;
        usrnameSession = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
        if(usrnameSession == null){
            response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
        }
    %>
```

this site will run well. So I think the reason is the <%%> block above.
So why this block does not work?
Note that i write these code in Netbeans, and run on Glassfish server :(
Any solution?

Comment: Are you aware that the redirect doesn't stop execution of the rest of code on the page ? You could use if{} else{} to avoid that.

Comment: Hi rickz, may I use below javascript instead using if{} else{}:
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.location = "somepage.jsp";
</script>

Comment: If you want to use javascript,then yes.